# Bring process to foreground

Tags: c, linux, process

I have a process (which reads and writes to terminal type) that has been exec'd by a background process. I can see it using ps.
Trying to bring it to foreground, this is what I attempted:

```
int main()

{

    FILE* fd = popen("pidof my_program","r");

    // ...
    // Some code to get the pid of my_program as mpid
    //...

    printf("pid of my_program is %d",mpid);
    signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
    setpgid(mpid,0); // Set program group id to pid of process
    tcsetpgrp(0,mpid); // Give it terminal stdin access
    tcsetpgrp(1,mpid); // Give it terminal stdout access
    return 0;
}
```

It isn't working though. Can someone help me on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it the "soft" way, by calling the shell command `fg` and pass it the pid (adviced).

If you want to code it, this is how fg/bg is coded into bash (don't don't don't):

```
static int
fg_bg (list, foreground)
     WORD_LIST *list;
     int foreground;
{
  sigset_t set, oset;
  int job, status, old_async_pid;
  JOB *j;

  BLOCK_CHILD (set, oset);
  job = get_job_spec (list);

  if (INVALID_JOB (job))
    {
      if (job != DUP_JOB)
    sh_badjob (list ? list->word->word : _("current"));

      goto failure;
    }

  j = get_job_by_jid (job);
  /* Or if j->pgrp == shell_pgrp. */
  if (IS_JOBCONTROL (job) == 0)
    {
      builtin_error (_("job %d started without job control"), job + 1);
      goto failure;
    }

  if (foreground == 0)
    {
      old_async_pid = last_asynchronous_pid;
      last_asynchronous_pid = j->pgrp;  /* As per Posix.2 5.4.2 */
    }

  status = start_job (job, foreground);

  if (status >= 0)
    {
    /* win: */
      UNBLOCK_CHILD (oset);
      return (foreground ? status : EXECUTION_SUCCESS);
    }
  else
    {
      if (foreground == 0)
    last_asynchronous_pid = old_async_pid;

    failure:
      UNBLOCK_CHILD (oset);
      return (EXECUTION_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'm running this on embedded linux machine where I only have busybox binaries and I don't have either fg, bg or jobs available. How do I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a process that is in the background or suspended, you can move it to the foreground with
the `fg` command. By default, the process most recently suspended or moved to the background moves to
the foreground. You can also specify which pid it is using to make it foreground.

Comment: But I'm running this on embedded linux machine where I only have busybox binaries and I don't have either fg, bg or jobs available. How do I do it then?